# How do I set the protocolVersion using the jdbc postgres driver?

Tags: postgresql, spatial-database, java

I attempted to concatenate a string to the url parameter of the below in order to set the protocolVersion, but I'm not sure how to keep the string in the url without altering the name of the database, so I kept getting a database name error.

```
String protocolVersion = "&2";
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database + protocolVersion;
Connection connection = null;
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
```

I am using PostgreSQL 9.2, but I was getting lag so I want to try to see if I can optimize by using an older protocol version.

Comment: This kind of general question is a better fit on Stack Overflow than it is here.

Comment: I attempted to migrate this post, but its owner is blocked from asking questions on SO.

Comment: Please use `EXPLAIN` on your query to figure out the slowness. Might be easily addressable with an index or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is formatted something like a URL with parameters delimited after the `?`. Per [the manual I found online](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/connect.html), it should be:

`String url = "jdbc:postgresql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database + "?protocolVersion=" + protocolVersion;`